# Why does my Ubuntu have a Hebrew font?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, fonts, input

Something weird is in my PC. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> it starts to type like this:

```
יקךךם 'םרךג
```

I did not choose this language, and my language bar still shows I'm typing English. My key mapping to change language isn't even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I don't even have Hebrew installed (it's not showing up under Text Entry or Language Support). How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Try to install hebrew font and then remove it.

Comment: I don't mind having it. I just can't find where the mapping is.

Comment: I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But... Do you want to get rid of this or you want to keep it???